# Последовательное чтение данных из Firestore

Tags: java, android, firestore

У меня есть 2 collection в Firestore из которых нужно читать данные последовательно. То есть сначала прочитать document1 из collection 1, а потом на основе document1 вытащить document2 из collection2.
Структура базы данных такая:
collection1.document1.collection2.document2

Для этого я думал реализовать CompletableFuture, чтобы 2 ассинхронных процесса (получение document1 и получение document2) связать в одну цепочку.

```
CompletableFuture<ArrayList<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> ReadData(String collectionPath){
    final CompletableFuture<ArrayList<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    Log.e(TAG,"Future execution has started");
    db.collection(collectionPath)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                Log.e(TAG,"Future execution is in progress");
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    docList.clear();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                        docList.add(document);
                    }
                    future.complete(docList);
                    Log.e(TAG,"Future execution has completed");
                } else {
                    Log.e("FirebaseDB", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    Log.e(TAG,"Future execution failed");
                    future.complete(null);
                }
            });
    return future;
}
```

Но это не работает:
мой future пролетает сразу до строки return future, при этом блок с addOnCompleteListener зависает.
Я предполагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что addOnCompleteListener - это ещё один ассинхронный процесс, который выполняется внутри моего future.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне переделать

```
db.collection(collectionPath)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {...})
```

в CompletableFuture, чтобы я смог выстроить цепочку последовательных чтений из db(Firestore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что никто не знает ответа. Спустя некоторое время я сам нарыл ответ:

```
Task<?> docTask = db.collection(collectionPath).get();
Tasks.whenAllComplete(docTask).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<?>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Task<?>>> task) {
....... }
```

То есть первый запрос в базу данных объявляем как Task
А затем у объекта Tasks есть whenAllComplete, где через запятую можно указать несколько таких квери с типом Task (у меня просто он 1), и на этот же Tasks вешаем OnCompleteListener, который выполнится только тогда, когда все таски внутри whenAllComplete завершены.
Кстати, внутрь этого  OnCompleteListener можно поместить ещё несколько тасков и там же внутри применить whenAllComplete и новый OnCompleteListener. Таким образом можно выстраивать процессы в цепочку.

Может быть будет кому-то полезно ))